# Heroku Application Error: OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, flask, heroku

This is my project directory:

```
├── Procfile
├── app.py
└── requirements.txt
```

`Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

app.run()
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
requests==2.24.0
urllib3==1.25.10
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

This is what I ran in the terminal:

```
$ git init
$ heroku create
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "test"
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

When I open the website, I get an `Application error` and when I check the logs I see:

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I checked and don't seem to have anything else running, what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

it should work.